# Python - Desmembrando arquivo texto

Tags: python, matriz, stream-de-arquivos

Boa noite,

Estou precisando separar umas linhas do arquivo e de acordo com a linha acrescentar em um outro arquivo. Ou seja, um arquivo que contem 6 palavras será adcionado, de acordo com a palavra para um arquivo especifico.

Essas 6 palavras pode aumentar para 8, 10, etc e ai terá que criar 8, 10 arquivos, e assim por diante.

Eu tentei em primeiro momento criar uma matriz na qual cada linha seria responsavel por uma linha que contivesse a palavra.

Mas não consegui, pois quanto eu tentava fazer acrescentar na linha, não tinha como, pois nao conseguia a nao ser que especificasse a entrada com linha e coluna.

Por exemplo, quero que todas as linhas contendo laranja seja direcionado para o arquivo laranja.txt e que todas as linhas contendo ameixa vá para o arquivo ameixa.txt.

A ideia seria fazer o codigo sem "if ameixa", "if laranja".

Eu tentei jogar as palavras em um vetor mas para jogar no arquivo nao consegui sem que tivesse o if...
Ex:

```
frutas = ['laranja', 'ameixa']

with open('frutas.txt', 'r') as arq_fruta:
  for line in arq_fruta:
    coluna = line.split()
    for i in range (len(frutas)):
      if(coluna[1] == variaveis[0]):
        laranja.append(coluna[0] +' '+ coluna[3]+'\n')
```

A última linha já não consegui colocar como um vetor por exemplo, algo como:

```
fruta[i].append(coluna[0] +' '+ coluna[3]+'\n') #só como exemplo, nao funciona
```

sendo que o fruta[0] seria o vetor de todas as linhas contendo somente laranja e fruta[1] todas as linhas com ameixa.

Tentei criar uma matriz, mas nao deu certo, pois a matriz pede a linha e coluna para entrada, mas nao tenho essas infos, ja que vou ler o e supostamente jogar para o arquivo.

E falando em arquivo, tambem tentei fazer algo que fosse "direto" mas tambem nao funciona.

```
for i in range(1, len(frutas)):
   arq = open(frutas[i]+'.txt','w')
   arq.writelines(fruta[i])
```

Tem alguma forma mais "correta" de fazer isso? Eu não obtive sucesso, somente com o codigo com "if" o que faria que tivesse muita alteracao se tivesse que incluir uma outra fruta por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma mais direta seria você criar uma lista de arquivos abertos, onde você tem um arquivo pra cada fruta. Assim você pode ter um código só que escreve em todos os arquivos diretamente sem precisar dividir em listas na memória. O código vai conseguir lidar com arquivos de qualquer tamanho pois escreve direto no destino.

```
frutas = ['laranja', 'ameixa']
arquivos = [open(fruta + '.txt', 'w') for fruta in frutas]

with open('frutas.txt', 'r') as arq:
    for linha in arq:
        for fruta, arquivo in zip(frutas, arquivos):
            if fruta in linha:
                arquivo.write(linha)
```

Se quiser mesmo separar em variáveis na memória, uma solução é combinar dicionários com listas, pode ser facilitado pelo `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections

frutas = ['laranja', 'ameixa']
por_fruta = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open('frutas.txt', 'r') as arq:
    for linha in arq:
        for fruta, arquivo in zip(frutas, arquivos):
            if fruta in linha:
                por_fruta[fruta].append(linha)
```

Assim você tem todas as listas no dicionário `por_fruta`... para gravar em arquivo depois:

```
for fruta, linhas in por_fruta.items():
    with open(fruta + '.txt', 'w') as f:
         f.writelines(linhas)
```

Comment: Obrigado nosklo, era algo como a primeira sugestão que eu estava procurando mesmo! melhor ainda que não precisou salvar em memoria antes de enviar para o arquivo e essa parte ficou bem dinâmica! o codigo está bem diferente do que eu costumo codificar, como os for's por exemplo! se tiver alguma dica de documento onde eu possa aprender mais sobre e voce puder sugerir, eu agradeço!